# Dataview get data from same List type with same content type from different sub sites

Tags: sharepoint-designer, data-view-web-part

I have a site collection with different sub sites:

```
                                  A (Root)

                    B (Program Site)    B (Program Site)

            C(Projects Site) D(Projects Site) E(Projects Site)
             Issues List         Issues List        Issues List
```

I'm trying to create a Dataview in Program site level where:
- Get All Issues from Projects sub sites
- With "priority"= Medium

Note: The issues site lists have the same content type = Issues and I need to do this with SharePoint designer.

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use Content Query Web Part (CQWP), example of solution you can see on: http://www.astaticstate.com/2011/05/customizing-content-query-web-parts.html